# Make Combo Box ItemsSource generic inside of UserControl to make it reusable for Collections of Multiple types

Tags: c#, wpf, generics, user-controls, dependency-properties

I am working on a `WPF` application and recently came across a requirement of making reusable `User Controls`.

I have two `User Controls` `InputUC` and `ComboBoxUC`. Both have `Label` with `TextBox` and `Label` with `ComboBox` respectively. I have successfully implemented the `InputUC` by defining required Dependency Properties.

The problem I am facing is in `ComboBoxUC`. I have a scenario in my application where I have to show `Collection` of `Cities`, `Customers`, `Salesmen` and some other entities in different places. Obviously each entity will offer different property names to `DisplayMemberPath`, `SelectedValuePath`, `SelectedValue` properties and different type of `Collection` as `ItemsSource` property of `ComboBox`.

I have searched on internet as well but didn't find any same solution.

The code I am trying is

`ComboBox` control in `ComboBoxUC.xaml`

```
<ComboBox Name="valuesComboBox" 
          Grid.Column="1"
          ItemsSource="{Binding ComboBoxItems}" 
          DisplayMemberPath="{Binding ComboBoxDisplayMemberPath}"
          SelectedValuePath="{Binding ComboBoxSelectedValuePath}"
          SelectedValue="{Binding ComboBoxValue}"
          IsEnabled="{Binding ComboBoxIsEnabled}"
          Style="{StaticResource ComboBox-Base}">
</ComboBox>
```

Code behind of `ComboBoxUC` in `ComboBoxUC.xaml.cs`

```
    public string ComboBoxLabel
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LabelProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LabelProperty, value); }
    }

    public bool ComboBoxIsRequired
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsRequiredProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsRequiredProperty, value); }
    }

    public long ComboBoxValue
    {
        get { return (long)GetValue(ValueProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueProperty, value); }
    }

    public bool ComboBoxIsEnabled
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(ValueEnabledProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ValueEnabledProperty, value); }
    }

    public ObservableCollection<CityViewModel> ComboBoxItems
    {
        get { return (ObservableCollection<CityViewModel>)GetValue(ValueItems); }
        set { SetValue(ValueItems, value); }
    }

    public string ComboBoxDisplayMemberPath
    {
        get { return GetValue(ValueDisplayMemberPath).ToString(); }
        set { SetValue(ValueDisplayMemberPath, value); }
    }

    public string ComboBoxSelectedValuePath
    {
        get { return GetValue(ValueSelectedValuePath).ToString(); }
        set { SetValue(ValueSelectedValuePath, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LabelProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ComboBoxLabel", typeof(string),
        typeof(ComboBoxUC), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsRequiredProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ComboBoxIsRequired", typeof(bool),
            typeof(ComboBoxUC), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ComboBoxValue", typeof(long),
            typeof(ComboBoxUC), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true, DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueEnabledProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ComboBoxIsEnabled", typeof(bool),
            typeof(ComboBoxUC), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata { BindsTwoWayByDefault = false, DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueItems = DependencyProperty.Register("ComboBoxItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<CityViewModel>),
            typeof(ComboBoxUC), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata { BindsTwoWayByDefault = false, DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueDisplayMemberPath = DependencyProperty.Register("ComboBoxDisplayMemberPath", typeof(string),
            typeof(ComboBoxUC), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata { BindsTwoWayByDefault = false, DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueSelectedValuePath = DependencyProperty.Register("ComboBoxSelectedValuePath", typeof(string),
            typeof(ComboBoxUC), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata { BindsTwoWayByDefault = true, DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });

    public ComboBoxUC()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

The code from the `Page` control where I am using this `UserControl` is

```
<local:ComboBoxUC ComboBoxLabel="City"
                  ComboBoxIsRequired="True"
                  ComboBoxValue="{Binding CustomerViewModel.customer_city_id}"
                  ComboBoxItems="{Binding Cities}"
                  ComboBoxDisplayMemberPath="city_name"
                  ComboBoxSelectedValuePath="city_id"
                  ComboBoxIsEnabled="{Binding Flags.AddOrUpdate}">
</local:ComboBoxUC>
```

Now I will use same above `xaml` in multiple places in my application.
The things that can vary in each case are:

- CustomerViewModel.customer_city_id
- Cities
- city_name
- city_id

I have correctly set the `DataContext` in `ComboBoxUC.xaml` and the current code for my `UserControl` works correctly for one type of `Collection (CityViewModel)`. I want to use the same code for other entities like `CustomerViewModel`, `SalesmanViewModel` etc. with obviously different property names.

I want the following code to be generic.

```
public ObservableCollection<CityViewModel> ComboBoxItems
{
     get { return (ObservableCollection<CityViewModel>)GetValue(ValueItems); }
     set { SetValue(ValueItems, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueItems = DependencyProperty.Register("ComboBoxItems", typeof(ObservableCollection<CityViewModel>),
                typeof(ComboBoxUC), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata { BindsTwoWayByDefault = false, DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });
```

I have tried `Collection` of `object` type as well but of course `object` type does not have any properties that I have in my entities.

Help will be appreciated as I am stuck and not able to move forward with the development from this point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of attempting to make the collections in the user control ore strongly-typed by making them generic, you should instead make them less strongly-typed; remember, the ItemsSource of the Combobox itself is simply of type 'object'.

I would suggest that you make your ComboBoxUC expose a DependencyProperty of type IEnumerable and bind that to the ComboBox ItemsSource. Then also expose a DependencyProperty of type DataTemplate and bind that to the ComboBox's ItemTemplate property. When using the user control you can then provide a simple DataTemplate to display the desired property instead of using DisplayMember path. For example, when you want to display City's in the ComboboxUC, you could do this:

```
<local:ComboBoxUC ItemsSource="{Binding Cities}">
  <local.ComboBoxUC.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <TextBlock Text="{Binding city_name}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
  </local:ComboBoxUC.ItemTemplate>
</local:ComboBoxUC/>
```

I would then expose the ComboBox's SelectedItem as a DependencyProperty of the user control and, if you absolutely must bind to the SelectedValuePath instead of the SelectedItem, use a ValueConverter.

To be honest, it feels like these user controls are a bit OTT. If all you're gaining is a label and some styling, the same could be achieved with retemplating the control in a resource dictionary and applying the template to each combobox you want to use in this manner.

Comment: My only concern is not just DisplayMemberPath property. I have to use SelectedValuePath and SelectedValue property as well. And I cannot just define a DataTemplate for each property I guess. If I will have to provide this long Item template in my Window/Page Xaml while adding user control then I might as well go back to separating this user control.

Comment: The DataTemplates (and, should you decide to do it, control templates) can be defined centrally in a resource dictionary so they only need to be defined once and can be used like this: <local:ComboBoxUC ItemTemplate="{StaticResource CityItemTeplate}"/>

Comment: Can you provide an example ?

Comment: SelectedValuePath can be derived via a ValueConverter on the SelectedValue property. Regardless, I still feel you're overcomplicating matters here and using a user-control to wrap a combo box simply to gain a label is over kill.

Comment: If you don't know or cannot help me in the approach I am attempting then you shouldn't answer. I am open to better approaches but with solid working examples. Not just names that do nothing but confuse things.

Comment: I'm sorry Umair but there was nothing in your question to suggest you were new to WPF and, if you're not new to it, then terms like ResourceDictionary, DataTemplate and ValueConverter should be second nature. I would very much encourage you to read about these terms before continuing along your current path as you will then undoubtedly be able to answer your own question.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing needed to change was the Type of `ObservableCollection` to `IEnumerable` as @ibebbs pointed out.

```
public IEnumerable ComboBoxItems
{
     get { return (IEnumerable)GetValue(ValueItems); }
     set { SetValue(ValueItems, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueItems = DependencyProperty.Register("ComboBoxItems", typeof(IEnumerable),
                typeof(ComboBoxUC), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata { BindsTwoWayByDefault = false, DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged });
```

This allowed me to use the same `UserControl` over the application and with `Collection` of different types and even with different property names.

Comment: _"I figured it out **myself**. The only thing needed to change was the Type of ObservableCollection to IEnumerable **as @ibebbs pointed out**."_ - that's an oxymoron if I ever read one and your answer borderline plagiarism

Comment: My intention was not to take any credit but to clearly describe what particular thing solved my issue in this scenario. As far as negative vote is concerned, That was my mistake and I have removed it. But still @ibebbs answer didn't solve my issue altogether. I just answered the particular thing that solved my issue in my answer and that is not plagiarism in my opinion.